# Python regular expression help needed

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I was trying to scape a link out of a .eml file but somehow I always get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are right. Just delete whitespaces and new lines from raw text.
For example:

```
link = re.findall("CONFIRM<([^\s]+)>", raw_email.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to get everything between `CONFIRM<` and `>`.

- Remove the spaces in the raw url by replacing them with empty strings.
- `(.*?)` will capture everything between `CONFIRM<` and `>`
- Use `.group(1)` to get the actual captured string

```
import re
def get_url(raw):
    raw = raw.replace(' ', '')
    url = re.search('CONFIRM<(.*?)>', raw).group(1)
    return url
```

For the test case given.

```
raw_url = 'Please click "CONFIRM" below. CONFIRM<https://app.rule.io/subscriber/optIn?token=3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG= ciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEssswrgTA3OCwic3Vic2NyaWJlckZvcm0iOjExOTAsImlzcyI6= Imh0dHBzOi8vYawetgg1bGUuaW8iLCJpYXQiOjE2MjM1NzkwMDYsImV4cCI6MTYyNDE4MzgwNiw= ibmJmIjoxNjIzNTc5MDA2LCJqdGkiOiJEbHMyeDJmcG5pZEhTWXVjwjwje-52uhXlj9efaEwzfI= Rruoiqc3RvUTZ8LgB6ALEAoL4>'
print(get_url(raw_url))
```

Will output

```
https://app.rule.io/subscriber/optIn?token=3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG=ciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEssswrgTA3OCwic3Vic2NyaWJlckZvcm0iOjExOTAsImlzcyI6=Imh0dHBzOi8vYawetgg1bGUuaW8iLCJpYXQiOjE2MjM1NzkwMDYsImV4cCI6MTYyNDE4MzgwNiw=ibmJmIjoxNjIzNTc5MDA2LCJqdGkiOiJEbHMyeDJmcG5pZEhTWXVjwjwje-52uhXlj9efaEwzfI=Rruoiqc3RvUTZ8LgB6ALEAoL4
```